# How to get the admin status of a Google Apps user

Tags: java, gwt, oauth, openid, google-apps

I have a GWT application, where users can sign on with their Google Apps account (OpenID Login). Now I want to be able to know, if the user signed on is an admin for this domain.

This already works with the following code:

```
private boolean isAdmin (String username) {
  boolean ret= false;

  if (username.indexOf ("@") > 0) username= username.substring (0, username
    .indexOf ("@"));

  AppsForYourDomainClient client= null;
  try {
    client= new AppsForYourDomainClient ("admin@orgapage.de", "password",
      "orgapage.de");

    UserEntry user= client.retrieveUser (username);
    if (user.getLogin ().getAdmin ().equals (Boolean.TRUE)) ret= true;
    else ret= false;
  }
  catch (Exception ex2) {
    log.severe (ex2.getMessage ());
    ex2.printStackTrace ();
  }

  return ret;
}
```

The problem is, that I have to enter the username and password of an admin of this domain to check for the current logged in user.

Is there a way to do this without having to know the password of an admin? Maybe with OAuth?

The only way to retrieve the admin status, I found so far, is the one above. Here is the documentation of it:

http://code.google.com/googleapps/domain/gdata_provisioning_api_v2.0_reference_java.html#Retrieve_Account_Example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use the Google Apps Marketplace, you can request read-only Provisioning API access to the Google Apps domain via Two-Legged OAuth. This would allow you to use your sample code above instead of needing a domain admin username/pass. See the docs at:

http://code.google.com/googleapps/marketplace/data_access.html
http://code.google.com/googleapps/marketplace/manifest.html

Jay

Comment: Thanks Jay! I figured by now, that this is the right way to go. Though I'm still having some issues with the Provisioning API. +1

Answer (score -1):

The `UserService` has a method called `isUserAdmin` for determining if the current user is an admin for the application.

[http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/users/UserService.html#isUserAdmin()](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/users/UserService.html#isUserAdmin%28%29)

Not sure if this is what you are looking for!

Comment: Thought so as well, but no. This method returns the Admin status of the AppEngine user, where the code is running. The code is always running in the same AppEngine account, while it can be deployed to different Google Apps domains from there. And I want to have the admin status of this Apps domain.